# php: how to pass self as parameter, and handle it once received

Tags: php, self

How to pass *self* to a global function

```
class A
{
  public static $A_var = "hello" ;

  private static  function A_function()
  {
    some_global_function( self ) ;
  }
}
```

And then receive it:

```
function some_global_function( $argo_self ) 
{
  echo $argo_self::A_var ;
}
```

Comment: self can not be passed as an argument...

Comment: So the goal in `some_global_function()` is to be able to call a static property from whatever class is passed in?

Comment: should I, then, pass the class's name, and let the receiver handle it from there.

Comment: If so, you will want to pass the class name, not `self`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`get_called_class`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php) which will give you the name of the class of your static method

```
class A
{ 
    public static $A_var = "hello" ;

    private static function A_function()
    { 
        some_global_function( get_called_class() ) ;
    }
}
```

You should note that to access the `$A_var` you'll need to do this, at the moment you're trying to access a constant named `A_var`

```
function some_global_function( $argo_self ) 
{
    echo $argo_self::$A_var ;
    // note the $ ---^ 
}
```

Comment: I must say that it is weird that you can use the String returned by get_called_class(), and then perform an action on it: **$my_string_argument::$A_var**

Answer (score 1):

You could get all available static fields via [ReflectionClass::getStaticProperties()](http://php.net/manual/de/reflectionclass.getstaticproperties.php):

```
private static  function A_function()
{
  // pass class name
  some_global_function( 'A' ) ;
}

function some_global_function( $className ) 
{
  $reflClass = new ReflectionClass($className);
  $staticProps = $reflClass->getStaticProperties();

  echo $staticProps['A_var'];
}
```

Live demo: http://codepad.org/6ZZjNtXC

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class ExampleClass {

    // Create loaded variable as to only init once
    static $loaded = false;

    // Create static variable to hold self
    static $self;

    // Create initialization function to assign self to self::$self
    public static function init() {

        // Assign the current class to self::$self
        self::$self = get_called_class();

        // Set self::$loaded to true to prevent double execution
        self::$loaded = true;
    }

    public static function someFunction() {

        // Check to see if static class has been initialized
        if(self::$loaded == false) {

            // Initialize static class
            self::init();
        }

        // Pass this static class to the destination function
        some_global_function(self::$self);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use $this variable to pass self

Comment: It's a `static` method, so `$this` isn't available.